# pass an Array of Int to LINQ Operators for Getting particular objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

I have an array of int and this array has Ids for Objects, i want to pass this array to a LINQ Operator and get all objects that has same Ids with array members..
And ***I don't want to use for loop for*** getting those objects, i just want to know and learn how to get these objects with array in LINQ
thanks in advance

```
public IEnumerable<ExhibitionPhoto> GetPhotosById(int[] ids)
{
   return _db.ExhibitionPhotos.Select();
}
```

Model:

```
public class ExhibitionPhoto
{
    [Key]
    public int ExhibitionPhotoId { get; set; }
    public int ExhibitionId { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }

    #region Navigational Properties
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ExhibitionId))]
    public Exhibition Exhibition { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) clause with [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8)

```
public IEnumerable<ExhibitionPhot> GetPhotosById(int[] ids)
{
   return _db.ExhibitionPhotos.Where(x => ids.Any(y => y == x.ExhibitionPhotoId)); 
}
```

---

`Where()`:

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

`Any()`:

> Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a condition.

Comment: @N'aix Kindly add code snippet instead of screenshots in your question. I am glad it helped.